# Destiny PS4 on-line gameplay geographically limited?

Tags: ps4, destiny

Just a quick question here, could not find an answer anywhere (perhaps I did not look properly).

My brother, in Spain, has a PS4. I (in Canada) would like to buy a PS4 too to play Destiny with him. Is that possible, or is there some kind of geographical restriction regarding whom you can play on-line with?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Likely it is geographically limited, but I don't have any evidence to back that up.

Comment: From my experience, it is not limited. I live in the US, and play with friends from Canada and Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During regular gameplay you will almost always get placed in the world of people near you physically in the world.

However there is no limit to gameplay connectivity in specific teams. I live in South America and regularly team up with people from UK, Australia and even Turkey using [DestinyLFG.net](http://destinylfg.net/)

You and your brother will be able to play online just fine, just don't forget to play in the same fireteam.

Answer (score -2):

Just a quick update: no, there is no geographic limitation. Just add whoever you want to your in-game contacts ('fireteam') and you are all set.

Comment: That's not really an update so much as repeating the accepted answer nearly two months later...